# External server as backend for Swift mobile app

Tags: php, swift, paypal, stripe-payments

I have created an app that uses Stripe and PayPal.  In order to get the token, I have created a local backend server on my Mac using XAMPP.

**// . . .  sending the token to our backend by making a HTTP POST request**

```
func postStripeToken(token: STPToken) {

    let URL = "http://localhost/ryde/payment.php"
    let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId,
                  "amount": Double(self.driverInfoView.rydeFare.text!)!,
                  "currency": "cad",
                  "description": self.riderName] as [String : Any]

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.post(URL, parameters: params, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in

        if let response = responseObject as? [String: String] {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: response["status"], message: response["message"], preferredStyle: .alert)

            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
        self.handleError(error as NSError)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

**payment.php**

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key  in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_**********************");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token =  $_POST['stripeToken'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$currency = $_POST['currency'];
// $description = $_POST['description'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's   card
try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"amount" => $amount*100, // Convert amount in cents to dollar
"currency" => $currency,
"source" => $token,
// "description" => $description)
);

// Check that it was paid:
if ($charge->paid == true) {
    $response = array( 'status'=> 'Success', 'message'=>'Payment has been charged!!' );
} else { // Charge was not paid!
    $response = array( 'status'=> 'Failure', 'message'=>'Your payment could NOT be processed because the payment system rejected the transaction. You can try again or use another card.' );
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
// The card has been declined
}

?>
```

The problem is that if I use the local server, I will have to always have XAMPP running so there are no hiccups in the mobile application.

How can I create an external backend rather than a local backend?

Comment: You want to put your code online for this, for example using something like Heroku: https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: I have a Heroku acct set up. Can you show me how i can implement this code?

Comment: You already built the code, you need to deploy it on heroku and their tutorial should be able to help you get there. Otherwise I'd recommend contacting their support team as this is a bit out of scope for StackOverflow

Comment: Ok thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is

1) Spin up a linux instance server running on Ubuntu. You can use AWS or heroku

2) install XAMPP on it via command line

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.3/xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-5-installer.run
```

3)Make it executable

```
sudo chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-5-installer.run
```

4) Run the installation

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-5-installer.run
```

5) Start Xampp. This will get Xampp up and running.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

5) Copy your PHP Code Folder to `/opt/lampp/htdocs`

6) Restart XAMPP by running the following command

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

7) Finally Change the URL in your swift code from localhost to your remote server URL

```
let URL = "Your server URL/payment.php"
```

That is all you need to do.

Comment: I added a Windows Server instance through AWS, will that work?

Comment: Would work. But the steps mentioned above might be a little different to configure it.

Comment: Ok i will try and figure it out. Thanks